# is it possible to compile c for many architectures on linux?

Tags: c, linux, compilation

I'm developing a few programs on my pc, that runs Ubuntu 64bit.

I'd like to run these applications on another pc, that runs on 32. Is possible to compile on my machine or do I need to recompile the applications on the other?

Comment: Yes. You can even compile programs that run on your smartphone, or even on microwave oven (if it is smart enough). It is called "cross-compilation".

Answer (score 1):

In general you need to provide the compiler an environment similar to the target execution environment. Depending on how similar or different one environment is to another, this may be simple or complicated.

Assuming the compiler is GCC, you should only need to add `-m32` to your compilation flags to make them work on a 32 bit system; assuming all other things are equal. Ensure you have the necessary 32-bit dependencies installed on your system (this means the base C library dependencies as well as a 32 bit version for each library your application links against).

Since you are only compiling for x86 on a 64 bit host, the path to this is generally simple. I would recommend however setting up a dedicated environment which you can use to compile -- typically some kind of `chroot` (See *pbuilder*, *schroot*, *chroot*, *debootstrap* and others).

Answer (score 0):

There are compiler settings/flags that should allow you to do this on your machine; which specific ones you need would depend on the compiler you are using.